# DataTable refuses to be populated with rows

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I can't seem to get my System.Data.DataTable to accept any new rows whatsoever.
Below is the code being used.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataTableToDGVTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow(); 
            dataRow["id"] = "1";
            dataRow["name"] = "Jesse";
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);

            //Tried this as well, still doesn't work
            //dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Jesse");
        }
    }
}
```

While debugging, I noticed DataTable.Rows.Count will increase from 0 to 1, however, DataTable.Rows.List remains null, as shown in the following picture[image: List remains null]

I've ran this code in .NET Framework 4.6, and just tried in 4.7.1 with both outcomes being identical.

Comment: Rows.Count is 1. That means the row is added successfully to the table. Why you need to check the List property? You need to check Rows.Count.

Comment: The list should show me that there is one row with info '{1, "Jesse"}'  in the DataRowCollection being the list property I'm looking at. Yes, Row.Count is 1, But there is literally null items in the List.

Comment: List being null could be some other issue... But that doesn't mean that the rows are not being added. You can read about the List property and understand what exactly should it returned when accessed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're inspecting the wrong part of the object. What you should be inspecting is `dataTable => rows => Results View => [0] => ItemArray`. See the below (more expanded version) of your code to better demonstrate.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

            var rowCount = dataTable.Rows.Count;
            Console.WriteLine(rowCount);

            var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow["id"] = "1";
            dataRow["name"] = "Jesse";
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);

            var rowCountAfterAdding = dataTable.Rows.Count;
            Console.WriteLine(rowCountAfterAdding);
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                foreach (var ia in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ia);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're right, now I do see the information. When I watch `dataTable.Rows[0]`, I expand that, and see the information in `ItemArray`. When I `dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable` my dataGridView1 creates another row, but nothing populates the cells. Which is what prompted me scouring the inspector to figure what wrongs, and then I saw null in list and thought that's what was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What does a watch `dataTable.Rows[0]` show?

Have you tried the example from [MSDN's DataTable class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx%20Msdn's%20DataTable%20Class)?

```
private static void ShowTable(DataTable table) {
  foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns) {
     Console.Write("{0,-14}", col.ColumnName);
  }
  Console.WriteLine();

  foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
     foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns) {
        if (col.DataType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
           Console.Write("{0,-14:d}", row[col]);
        else if (col.DataType.Equals(typeof(Decimal)))
           Console.Write("{0,-14:C}", row[col]);
        else
           Console.Write("{0,-14}", row[col]);           
     }
     Console.WriteLine();
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Just another quick comment after your comment about empty control. `dataTable` is a local variable.

Comment: You know what, when I set it to watch, the object does actually show up in the watch view. I'm pretty sure @gilliduck is right, I'm inspecting the wrong part of the object... Though, when I `dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable` my dataGridView1 creates another row, but nothing populates the cells.

Comment: There may be something wrong with the binding. For example, your DataTable is is a local variable.

Comment: Ok, I just declared `dataTable` globally within `Form1`. Still not showing the data in the `dataGridView1`. It is creating a new row within the view, but the cells in the new row remain empty.

Answer (score 1):

The List property of DataRowCollection class according to documentation is not avaible for you to use. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

You see List property in debugger because DataRowCollection is inherited from InternalDataCollectionBase and in that class the List property is protected. See this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.internaldatacollectionbase.list(v=vs.110).aspx)

So that is why you get the error and you should not be looking at the List property. That is the wrong object.